# Invalid Bitmap format in OpenGl

Tags: android, opengl-es, bitmap, rajawali

I use Rajawali library in my app.

I am trying to create png images with option

```
options.inPurgeable = true;
options.inInputShareable = true;
options.inSampleSize = sampleSize;
options.inDither = false;
options.inScaled = false;
options.inPreferredConfig=Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
```

since i think it reduces memory usage.But it cause a error at

```
GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, mBitmapFormat, mBitmap, 0);
```

in the class ASingleTexture;

But if i remove

```
options.inPreferredConfig=Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
```

then no error occur but use high memory.How to solve this issue

Comment: what error is happening exactly? can you post your stack-trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, the bitmaps you use for OpenGL textures need to be with ARGB_8888 config. Sure, each bitmap will require more memory this way, but here are a few points to remember:

1. OpenGL textures are saved in native memory which doesn't have the same limitations as regular memory allocated for apps.
2. Once you've created your texture, you don't need to hold the bitmap anymore. Call recycle on the bitmap immediately after the texture is loaded, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

What is the dimension of your image. Is it a [power of two](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_two)? If not, change the dimension with an image editor and try again.

Comment: The image size is 512X512 .As i said id i remove options.inPreferredConfig=Bitmap.Config.RGB_565; no error will occur.Otherwise cause error

Comment: In my case this issue was caused by a bitmap of size 1 x 64 . Apparently 1 is not considered a power of 2 on the Samsung Galaxy Y.